# Extract String Between Slashes, But Second Slash May Not Exists

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to extract usernames from a URL that's captured in a form. I do have the below regex, but the issue is that **the second forward slash may not exist**. Here are the examples:

**Sample URLs**
`https://test.site.com/u/username`
`https://test.site.com/u/username/pref/summary`

I'm trying to extract the `username`.

**Current Regex**
`/u/(.*?)/`

The current one I have above successfully extracts the `username`, but **only when there is another `/` after the username.** The second `/` needs to be optional; it may or may not be there, and there may or may not be more after that.

I just couldn't find the correct regex to make the second `/` optional (using `?` at the end didn't help) but not exactly "optional," if that makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change it to `/u/([^/]*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/u/([^/]*)` will match as many non-`/` characters after `/u/` as possible.

It will not match `pref` and `summary`,
because `[^/]` matches any character *other than* `/`,
so `[^/]*` matches a string (as long as possible)
of characters other than `/`. 
Consider: if your pattern is `B[aeiou]*`
and your input is `Beetles` (or `Beethoven`),
it will match only `Bee`,
stopping at (before) the first character that isn’t a vowel. 
Similarly, `[^/]*` stops at (before) the first occurrence of `/`.

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly it, but I don't get it! How is this not capturing strings past the other forward slashes, like "pref" and "summary" in my examples?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Makes sense now! Cheers.